# How to pass modified data from child component to parent component in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently learning Next.js and working on a small project. I have a Canvas component and a child component called Preview. In the Preview component, I'm manipulating data received from the parent (Canvas) and obtaining a new result. My question is, how can I pass this modified data back from the Preview component to the Canvas component?

Code Examples:

Canvas component:

```
// Canvas.js
'use client'
import Preview from '@/components/Preview'

const Canvas = (props) => {
    
    const demoData = {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <div><Preview data={demoData} /></div>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Canvas
```

Preview component:

```
// Preview.js
const Preview = (props) => {
    /*
Manipulate data received from Canvas to obtain a new result
...
...
*/
    return (
        <div>
            {props.width}
            {props.height}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Preview
```

I've created a Canvas component with a child Preview component. In the Preview component, I manipulate the data received from the Canvas component. Now, I want to send this modified data back to the Canvas component.

Comment: What does "*manipulate data to obtain a new result*" mean? Does this happen only on some kind of event, or every time the preview is rendered? What is the canvas supposed to do with the updated data - and *when* does it get updated? What does the canvas do with the initial data in the mean time?

Comment: I apologize, I should clarify the problem more. In its simplest form, what I need is,
according to the structure in the example, to pass data from the child component, Preview, to the parent component, Canvas.

Comment: That's not how react works. Data (state, what to render) is only passed down. Updates may be passed back up in the form of events/callbacks.

Comment: This sounds like [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/183280). What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve with those two components?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass down a function to the child component:

```
// Canvas.js

'use client'

import Preview from '@/components/Preview'

const Canvas = (props) => {
    
    const demoData = {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    }

    const handleDataUpdate = (data) => {
      // Do something with updated data
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div><Preview data={demoData} onDataUpdate={handleDataUpdate} /></div>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Canvas
```

You can then call `props.onDataUpdate({ ... })` with the updated data in `Preview.js`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm encountering the same problem again. I want to somehow assign a value to handleDataUpdate in my Preview component and use this value again in my Canvas component.

Comment: You could store the `demoData` in state (useState) and then update that state with the updated data inside `handleDataUpdate`, which will then pass the updated data down to the child component again.